# JSON.stringify odd behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I'm wrapping up some values to send back to an ASP.NET MVC controller action. I'm getting Invalid JSON primitive exceptions, but I'm using JSON.stringify and am confused.

I build up a search value holding called `searchValues`. Putting `console.log(JSON.stringify({ "values": searchValues }));` in my code and opening Chrome's console outputs the following

```
{"values":["name_last:foo"]}
```

I use the exact some bit of code sans the `console.log` usage to populate the `data` parameter to the ajax call. However, watching the call in Fiddler, the request being sent looks like such

```
0=%7B&1=%22&2=v&3=a&4=l&5=u&6=e&7=s&8=%22&9=%3A&10=%5B&11=%22&12=n&13=a&14=m&15=e&16=_&17=l&18=a&19=s&20=t&21=%3A&22=f&23=o&24=o&25=%22&26=%5D&27=%7D
```

I'm using this in a Kendo grid but am specifying it to be sent as post as such:

```
    $("#search-preview").kendoGrid({
        columns: ...column stuff...,
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/SearchPreview",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({"values": searchValues}),
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And I can see in Fiddler it being sent in the request body and not being appended to the URL such as if it were a GET. What's going on here?

Edit:

Adding what the entire Fiddler request looks like:

```
POST http://localhost/MvcTestBed/SearchPreview HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 149
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://localhost
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost/MvcTestBed
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: .... asp.net cookie fluff ....

0=%7B&1=%22&2=v&3=a&4=l&5=u&6=e&7=s&8=%22&9=%3A&10=%5B&11=%22&12=n&13=a&14=m&15=e&16=_&17=l&18=a&19=s&20=t&21=%3A&22=f&23=o&24=o&25=%22&26=%5D&27=%7D
```

Edit 2:

I've experimented with the `processData` and `traditional` settings on the jQuery ajax constructor, and the best I've gotten is for the post body to now look like

```
[object Object]
```

Comment: It looks like the string is treated like an array of characters instead of used directly. Maybe `data` is supposed to be an object, not a string?

Comment: I'm not intensely familiar with kendo, but are you certain that it expects you to do the stringifcation yourself? The frameworks I've worked with expect you to just give them the basic JSON object, and they will stringify it as needed during the request (possibly based on the content-type)

Comment: @Katana314 I was pretty sure that their read property is simply being passed to a jQuery ajax call. I tried as you suggested and took away the JSON.stringify altogether. It didn't change the behavior, though. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Something is using $.param on your json string. jQuery does not do that, so i suspect it has something to do with kendo

Comment: @KevinB I want to make multiple accounts just to vote your answer up. Post as answer, please. I inverted the call to setup the kendoGrid within the `success` parameter of an ajax call instead of letting the call to `.kendoGrid` do all the work.

Comment: @Bigsby would you provide result code? I have the same problem

Comment: @D0dger don't let Kendo handle the transport. That was my solution. I invert the call to only mess with the Kendo component in the success handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the results you're getting in fiddler, it looks like something is calling $.param on your json string. jQuery does not do that, so it must be kendo grid.

One solution would be to make the ajax request directly, then in the success initialize the grid with the result.

Answer (score 0):

After some research my solutions is use `read` as a function:

```
$("#search-preview").kendoGrid({
    columns: ...column stuff...,
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: function (options) {
                url: "/SearchPreview",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify({"values": searchValues}),
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
                    options.success(result);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    options.error(result);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```